# Conway, showing analytic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that if $G$ is a region and suppose that $ f: G \to \mathbb{C}~$   is analytic such that $f(G)$ is a subset of a circle, then $f$ is constant.

in the section with this exercise, I learn that an analytic function preserves angles btw curves if $f'(z) \neq 0 $ and Mobius transformation.

My attempt is that let $ A = \{z \in G : f'(z) \neq 0 \} $.  Then for any $z_o \in A $ , since $f$ is continuous and since $ f(G)$ is a subset of a circle, then the angle of the images of any two curves thru $z_o$ is $ 0, \pi$.  But  $f$ preserve angle so the only way this is possible is if $ f$ is constant on the set $A$.

I don't know if this is correct or not and what about the set of points $z$ that $f'(z) = 0$ ??? thank you .

Comment: take a point $z_0$ were the derivative is not $0$ and look  at the image by $f$ of a small open disk centered at $z_0$, you'll see that when the radius becomes very small, $f(z) \approx f(z_0) + (z-z_0)f'(z_0)$ which is an open disk (this is a starting point for the open mapping theorem stated by copper.hat )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is a non constant analytic function on the region $G$ then it is an open map. Since the circle has an empty interior, we must have that $f$ is constant.

Here is another approach which chooses some path such that $f(z)$ is not
contained in a circle.

Suppose we have $z_0 \in G$ such that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$. If such a point
does not exist then $f$ is constant.

Suppose the circle is given by $\{ w | |w -w_0| =r \}$, and let
$\phi(t) = z_0 +t d$. Note that $\phi(0) = z_0$
and $\phi'(0) = d$.

Consider $g(t) = |f(\phi(t))-w_0|^2$. Then, by hypothesis, $g$ is constant
in a neighbourhood of $0$. We have
$g'(0) = 2\ \mathfrak{R}( \overline{f(z_0)-w_0 }) f'(z_0) d$, hence by choosing
$d = {{f(z_0)-w_0} \over f'(z_0)}$ we get
$g'(0) = 2 r^2 >0$, a contradiction.

Hence $f'(z) = 0$ for $z \in G$.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  I see that you use the open mapping theorem to show this but is there any other simpler way to prove this since the section is almost the beginning of Conway text volume 1 and I haven't learned about the open mapping theorem yet at this point.  Is there any other way to show this using mobius trans or the fact that analytic function preserve angles since this is what the section is about.

Comment: @Khoata: I added another approach.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I follow your second argument up to the point when you take derivative of $g(t)$.  I thought that the function $ |z|^2 $ is nowhere analytic though so how can you take the derivative of it? Plus I never saw the rule of $ \frac{d}{dz} |z|^2 = 2|z| $ I know $ \frac{d}{dz} z^2 = 2 z $ though.  maybe I misunderstood what you meant.  thank you again.

Comment: I am taking the derivative with respect to $t$ a real variable. You are correct that $z \mapsto |z|^2$ is not analytic. Expand $g(t)$ using $|z|^2 = \bar{z} z$, or think of it as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I think I understand it now. Btw, the reasoning that I try in the original question, do you think it is correct??

Comment: @Khoata: Your idea is correct. It is similar to what I have above except I avoid dealing with angles by choosing the direction $d$ above.

Comment: Huh? The circle has connected proper subsets. I don't understand your point.

Comment: @Phibetakappa You need to elaborate your argument, I don't know what it is, perhaps adding an answer would be netter than adding comments to this answer?

Comment: @Phibetakappa Yes, if the set is open you can eliminate countable many points and it is still connected. There are uncountably many paths joining two points.

Comment: Thanks that's what I want to know.

Comment: @copper.hat I think $$g'(0) = 2 \mathfrak {R} \left [ \overline  {\left ( f \left (z_0 \right ) - w_0 \right )} f' \left (z_0 \right ) d \right ].$$ Can you please show up your calculation?

Comment: @Phibetakappa: It looks like I made a mistake in computation, thanks for catching that, I will fix it when I get a chance.

Comment: @Phibetakappa I had a missing real part and conjugation. Same general idea in any case.

Comment: @copper.hat Now it looks fine. Upvoted. Very nice explanation. +1